# Index is not used with table inheritance

Tags: postgresql, index, partitioning, execution-plan, inheritance

I have a PostgreSQL 9.0.12 database with a master table and 2 child tables. My tables:

```
CREATE TABLE test2 (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    coll character varying(15),
    ts timestamp without time zone
);
CREATE INDEX ON test2(ts);

CREATE TABLE test2_20150812 (
    CHECK ( ts >= timestamp '2015-08-12' AND ts < timestamp '2015-08-13' )
) INHERITS (test2);

CREATE TABLE test2_20150811 (
    CHECK ( ts >= timestamp '2015-08-11' AND ts < timestamp '2015-08-12' )
) INHERITS (test2);

CREATE INDEX ON test2_20150812(ts);
CREATE INDEX ON test2_20150811(ts);
VACUUM FULL ANALYZE;
```

My select queries' explain result (There is not any rows in db):

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) select * from test2 WHERE ts >= '2015-08-11' ORDER BY ts DESC;

 Sort  (cost=89.87..92.09 rows=887 width=31) (actual time=0.245..0.245 rows=0 loops=1)
   Sort Key: public.test2.ts
   Sort Method:  quicksort  Memory: 17kB
   Buffers: shared read=2
   ->  Result  (cost=0.00..46.44 rows=887 width=31) (actual time=0.087..0.087 rows=0 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared read=2
         ->  Append  (cost=0.00..46.44 rows=887 width=31) (actual time=0.078..0.078 rows=0 loops=1)
               Buffers: shared read=2
               ->  Seq Scan on test2  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=31) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Filter: (ts >= '2015-08-11 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
               ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on test2_20150812 test2  (cost=7.68..23.22 rows=443 width=31) (actual time=0.024..0.024 rows=
0 loops=1)
                     Recheck Cond: (ts >= '2015-08-11 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
                     Buffers: shared read=1
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on test2_20150812_ts_idx  (cost=0.00..7.57 rows=443 width=0) (actual time=0.016..0.016
 rows=0 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: (ts >= '2015-08-11 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
                           Buffers: shared read=1
               ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on test2_20150811 test2  (cost=7.68..23.22 rows=443 width=31) (actual time=0.033..0.033 rows=
0 loops=1)
                     Recheck Cond: (ts >= '2015-08-11 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
                     Buffers: shared read=1
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on test2_20150811_ts_idx  (cost=0.00..7.57 rows=443 width=0) (actual time=0.026..0.026
 rows=0 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: (ts >= '2015-08-11 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
                           Buffers: shared read=1
 Total runtime: 0.320 ms
(23 rows)
```

However if I change column `coll` from `character varying(15)` to `character varying(255)`, and do these steps again;

```
CREATE TABLE test2 (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    coll character varying(255),
    ts timestamp without time zone
);
```

Explain output is (There is not any rows in db):

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) select * from test2 WHERE ts >= '2015-08-11' ORDER BY ts DESC;

 Sort  (cost=42.47..43.18 rows=287 width=157) (actual time=0.028..0.028 rows=0 loops=1)
   Sort Key: public.test2.ts
   Sort Method:  quicksort  Memory: 17kB
   ->  Result  (cost=0.00..30.75 rows=287 width=157) (actual time=0.020..0.020 rows=0 loops=1)
         ->  Append  (cost=0.00..30.75 rows=287 width=157) (actual time=0.015..0.015 rows=0 loops=1)
               ->  Seq Scan on test2  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=157) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Filter: (ts >= '2015-08-11 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
               ->  Seq Scan on test2_20150812 test2  (cost=0.00..15.38 rows=143 width=157) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops
=1)
                     Filter: (ts >= '2015-08-11 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
               ->  Seq Scan on test2_20150811 test2  (cost=0.00..15.38 rows=143 width=157) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops
=1)
                     Filter: (ts >= '2015-08-11 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
 Total runtime: 0.063 ms
(12 rows)
```

Is there any way for using indexes on the child tables in this new condition?

Comment: Each question is supposed to be useful to the general public. The Postgres version must *always* be included with questions like that. ***How*** did you change column `coll` exactly? Did you `VACUUM ANALYZE` all involved tables before running the query afterwards?

Comment: Follow up to [this previous question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/110910/3684).

Comment: @Erwin Thank you for feedback. I edit my question and add them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of this is **unrelated to inheritance and partitioning**. It's about indexing and query plans in general.

The row size is much bigger for your second try: `width=157` vs. `width=46`. Postgres will even *more readily* use an index for wider rows. Possible reasons for the unexpected sequential scan include:

- You have substantially fewer rows in your tables for the second test as indicated by planner estimates: `rows=143` vs. `rows=357`. It does not pay to look up an index for only few rows to sort.
- Or statistics are outdated leading to misguided planner estimates (Postgres only *thinks* there would be fewer rows).
- The index size may have been bloated as a side-effect of rewriting the tables. `REINDEX` or `VACUUM FULL` would repair that.

Run `ANALYZE` on all involved tables and try again - with the same number of rows in all tables. You should see bitmap index scans again. If the phenomenon persists, provide the output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`, not just `EXPLAIN`.

#### After question update

As long as you read the *whole table*, an index is of limited use. If you query a **single table** with a matching index, so that readily sorted rows can be read from the index and Postgres can *skip the sort step altogether*, you'll see an **index scan**.

That's not possible when multiple tables have to be combined. This [**SQL fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3aa47/1) with 10k rows per child and valid statistics shows **bitmap index scans** as expected. After repeating the query a couple of times (as soon as the whole table is cached), Postgres may skip the index and switch to **sequential scans**, which have become cheaper now.

Postgres is obviously not smart enough to understand the mutually excluding check constraints, which would allow to append readily sorted results from each table *as is*. You *could* force that by manually instructing it:

```
(SELECT * FROM test2_20150812 ORDER BY ts DESC)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM test2_20150811 ORDER BY ts DESC);
```

However, Postgres should be smart enough to use **Merge Append** (cheap method to combine pre-sorted sets). In my local tests on PostgreSQL **9.4** I actually see **index scans** on each partition, combined with **Merge Append**. That plan is better, but it's not that much faster than sequential scans because, remember!, as long as you read the *whole table*, an index is of limited use.

```
'QUERY PLAN'
'Merge Append  (cost=0.73..16866.41 rows=200001 width=45)'
'  Sort Key: test.ts'
'  ->  Index Scan Backward using test_ts_idx on test  (cost=0.13..8.14 rows=1 width=528)'
'        Index Cond: (ts >= '2015-08-11 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)'
'  ->  Index Scan Backward using test_20150811_ts_idx on test_20150811  (cost=0.29..6594.01 rows=100000 width=45)'
'        Index Cond: (ts >= '2015-08-11 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)'
'  ->  Index Scan Backward using test_20150812_ts_idx on test_20150812  (cost=0.29..6594.29 rows=100000 width=45)'
'        Index Cond: (ts >= '2015-08-11 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)'
```

I don't get the same plan with Postgres 9.3 (testing on sqlfiddle). Must be a limitation of pg 9.3. (?)

But since you are using the **outdated version 9.0**, none of that is available to you.
[Merge Append was introduced with 9.1.](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CABRT9RBbqEAZ37JMLq4cVTEJ5zTnzSFGBiXNZg-S6ctFSig+QQ@mail.gmail.com#CABRT9RBbqEAZ37JMLq4cVTEJ5zTnzSFGBiXNZg-S6ctFSig+QQ@mail.gmail.com)

You get more interesting results when limiting the result to few rows. `varchar(15)` or `varchar(255)` has very little impact on the query plan. The wider type favors indexes some more.

[Your added fiddle with some more test queries.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/53918/19)

About testing indexes on SQL Fiddle:

- [PostgreSQL partial index unused when created on a table with existing data](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/99323/postgresql-partial-index-unused-when-created-on-a-table-with-existing-data/99324#99324)

Comment: I try these scenarios;

 I add 10000 row to each child table. After that I run  "VACUUM FULL ANALYZE". Result is same, db uses seq scan. 

 I try it postgres 9.3 into sqlfiddle; http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/307c0/4 . When coll character value 32, db use seq scan. If coll character value is changed to 15, db uses index.

Comment: @umut: Your fiddle does not test what you describe. You only insert a hand full of rows, without giving Postgres the chance to update statistics. (Even with updated statistics, Postgres is not going to use an index for just a hand full of rows.) I added a proper fiddle and a link to more.

Comment: thank you for your help. These anwers are very useful for me. I think it solve my sql problem :).

Comment: I try your sqlfiddle with more rows (1 M data for each child table). Postgresql uses seq scan in this situation. sqlfidle new link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/53918/1 .

Comment: @umut; I see *bitmap index scans* in your fiddle. The only seq. scan is on the parent table `test2`, which makes sense because that one's empty.

Comment: You are right. First time bitmap index scan is used. After that I execute same query 3 or 4 times, result changes to seq. scan.

Comment: @umut: The matter is complex. I added more details.